# Maven - can't download fasterxml.jackson

Tags: java, maven, jackson

In maven pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
```

This 3 libs can't be downloaded by maven, but all other libs could be downloaded successfully.

I tried this on 2 computer in different network environment, the result is the same.

**Error message in eclipse:**

```
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:bundle:2.5.0
```

Any suggestion on how to check why?

Comment: Please show us the error message that you get

Comment: @AaronDigulla Question updated.

Comment: Why `<type>bundle</type>`? Can you try to remove it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`<type>bundle</type>` is not appropriate here.

Try :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am wondering when search in maven why for version 2.5.0, it only provide the bundle option, not single jar option, and that's major reason why I made the mistake.

Comment: @Eric Wang same thing happened to me maybe a bug in STS. I only see bundles after version 2.3 jar

Comment: @Airduster I think this is very uncareful mistake, a careful team should try to help others avoid issues like this.

Comment: @Eric Wang well... that is what stackoverflow is for... we are all 1 big team :D

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to edit the properties and select 'jar' instead of 'bundle', See an example below,

[image]

[image]

This will resolve the issue if maven can't download it.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add the dependency. I got the same error. once I removed line **bundle**. Issue resolved.