# Gradle unable to resolve Dropwizard 1.2.0

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dropwizard

I would like to use the most recent version of Dropwizard, unfortunately I cannot, because Gradle is unable to resolve it.

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
group 'com.gaboratorium'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    dropwizardVersion = '1.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Application
    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:${dropwizardVersion}"
    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-db:${dropwizardVersion}"
    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:${dropwizardVersion}"
    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:${dropwizardVersion}"
    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:${dropwizardVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Using jcenter repository instead
- IntelliJ > **Invalidate caches / Restart**
- Using an older version instead; the only one I could make work was `0.8.2`

Did anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of the gradle output?

Comment: This works for me using Gradle 4.0. I would check the network/proxy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out my issue was that proxying was set up in my IntelliJ thanks to a previous project, which I was not aware of. However during my research for the problem I have found some relevant answers to this question, which I am going to place here for future reference:

- [IntellijIDEA not recognizing classes specified in Maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046764/intellijidea-not-recognizing-classes-specified-in-maven-dependencies)
- [Maven - can't download fasterxml.jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049687/maven-cant-download-fasterxml-jackson)
- [Gradle build doesn't download dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485819/gradle-build-doesnt-download-dependencies)